# Django, How to import model class to another model class?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this two app name Business and ChartofAccounts,

[image]

in my business.models i have

```
class businessType(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    RecordStatus = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)
```

and my ChartofAccounts.models i have

```
class ChartOfAccount(models.Model):
    AccountNo = models.IntegerField()
    Account_Name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Account_Type = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Details_Type = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    BusinessTypeID = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    RecordStatus = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)
```

I dont know how to import the business.models in my ChartofAccounts App, any ideas?

what i tried is

```
from myAccounting import Business
```

and the error is

[image]

**UPDATE**

when i tried this

```
from Business.models import Business

BusinessTypeID = models.ForeignKey('Business.Business', related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

the error says

[image]

UPDATE

```
from business.models import business
```

i rename my Business app to business app same goes to chartofAccounts but same error

[image]

Comment: It should be `from myAccounting.models import Business`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myAccounting.models'

Comment: but the app is named `Business`, hence it should be `from Business.models import ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined in the `models` module, hence you import this with:

```
from Business.models import Business
```

the name of the app is `Business`, so it should be `Business.models`, not `myAccounting.models`.

That being said, it might be easier to refer to the model with a string literal, then you do not need to import this at all:

```
from django.db import models

class ChartOfAccount(models.Model):
    AccountNo = models.IntegerField()
    Account_Name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Account_Type = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Details_Type = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    BusinessTypeID = models.ForeignKey('Business.Business', related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    RecordStatus = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)
```

This also helps avoind *circular imports*, like [@RHSmith159 says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60267030/django-how-to-import-model-class-to-another-model-class/60267065#comment106602702_60267065).

> **Note**: modules and field names are normally written in `slug_case`, not `PerlCase`. Therefore it is advisable to name your app `business` instead of <s>`Business`</s>, and the field `account_no`, instead of <s>`AccountNo`</s>.

Comment: using a string literal can also help avoid circular imports

Comment: @kaito: but that can not be the error, since your error message states a different line content than the one in the answer. It says `from myAccounting.models import Business`, see the bottom part of the error message. Your line 2 of that file is wrong.

Comment: @kaito: well of course you need to *rename* your module and directory structure as well. I however advice to first solve your problem, and then consider making your program in accordance with PEP-8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: i follow your answer and yet i receive this error """from business.models import businessType"""

Comment: @kaito: did you name it `businessType`, or `BusinessType`? Did you rename the module(s) properly?